# End-of-line identifier in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net

What end-of-line identifier should I use (for example, for output to text files)?

There are many choices:

- vbCrLf
- vbNewLine (apparently an alias of vbCrLf)
- ControlChars.CrLf
- ControlChars.NewLine
- Environment.NewLine
- A static member in some C# class in the application (requires mixed-language solution): public static string LINEEND = "\r\n";
- `Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(13) & Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.ChrW(10)` (generated by the Visual Studio designer, at least [Visual Basic 2005 Express Edition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_Studio_Express#Visual_Basic_Express), for a TextBox with property *Multiline* set to True when <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Return</kbd> is used while editing property *Text*.)

What is best practice?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I believe it generally makes most sense to use `Environment.NewLine` as the new-line identifier, for a number of reasons:

- It is an **environment-dependent** read-only variable. If you happen to be running your program on Linux (for example), then the value will simply be `\n`.
- `vbCrLf` is a legacy constant from the VB6 and earlier languages. Also, it's not environment-independent.
- `\r\n` has the same issue of not being environment-dependent, and also can't be done nicely in VB.NET (you'd have to assign a variable to `Chr(13) & Chr(10)`).
- Controls exists in the `Microsoft.VisualBasic` namespace, effectively making it a legacy/backwards-compatibility option, like `vbCrLf`. Always stay clear of legacy code if possible.

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` does not (seem to) work in constant expressions. `vbNewLine` does (but I haven't checked the others)

Answer (score 6):

`Environment.NewLine` simply because it is environment dependent and behaves differently on different platforms.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on you programming style, you may choose:

- ControlChars class, if you always use VB and other parts of your code use VB standards (how do you declare variables? As Integer or As Int32? Integer is VB, Int32 is common between every .NET language). Anyway, just if you have already married VB. Otherwise..
- Environment for a generic, language and environment independend way (my suggestion)

I think the worst would be the use of retrocompatibility functions, like vbCrLf (or CInt() and so on)