# VB.NET: identifier for TAB?

Tags: .net, vb.net

What identifier should I use for TAB (e.g. for output to text files)?

There are many choices:

- vbTab
- ControlChars.Tab
- A constant (or public member) in my application set to Chr(9)

What is best practice? And why?

Comment: Chr(13) is vbCr, not vbTab... vbTab would be Chr(9)

Comment: @Thomas Levesque: corrected now.

Comment: Related: *[End-of-line identifier in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399268)* (for newline)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Thumb up for ControlChars.Tab! vb* constants are there for backward compatibility, avoid them.

Comment: Just because they’re there for backwards compatibility is no reason to avoid them. A better reason is that there are other alternatives that fit better with the style of the .NET framework, and that `vbTab` is of type `String` instead of type `Char`.