# Regex VB.Net Regex.Replace

Tags: regex, vb.net

I'm trying to perform a simple regex find and replace, adding a tab into the string after some digits as outlined below.

From

```
a/users/12345/badges
```

To

```
a/users/12345   /badges
```

I'm using the following:

```
s = regex.replace(s, "(a\/users\/\d*)("a\/users\/\d*\t)", $1 $2")
```

But im clearly doing something wrong.

Where am I going wrong, I know its a stupid mistake but help would be gratefully received.

VBVirg

Comment: `\t` is not a tab in VB.net - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410462/vb-net-identifier-for-tab

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve that with a mere look-ahead that will find the position right before the last `/`:

```
Dim s As String = Regex.Replace("a/users/12345/badges", "(?=/[^/]*$)", vbTab)
```

Output:

```
a/users/12345   /badges
```

See [IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/utUNON)

Or, you can just use `LastIndexOf` owith `Insert`:

```
Dim str2 As String
Dim str As String = "a/users/12345/badges"
Dim idx = str.LastIndexOf("/")
If idx > 0 Then
   str2 = str.Insert(idx, vbTab)
End If
```

Comment: You can probably ditch the regex and just do a string replace `"/badges"` to `vbTab & "/badges"`

Comment: Unless there is anything else. I have also added another non-regex solution now. @vbvirg20, is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Or is `Dim s As String = "a/users/12345/badges".Replace("/badges", vbTab + "/badges")` enough (meaning `/badges` is always a known substring)?

Answer (score 0):

When I read, "adding a tab into the string after some digits" I think there could be more than one set of digits that can appear between forward slashes.  This pattern:

```
"/(\d+)/"
```

Will capture only digits that are between forward slashes and will allow you to insert a tab like so:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim str As String = "a/54321/us123ers/12345/badges"
        str = Regex.Replace(str, "/(\d+)/", String.Format("/$1{0}/", vbTab))

        Console.WriteLine(str)
        Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub
End Module
```

Results (NOTE: The tab spaces can vary in length):

```
a/54321 /us123ers/12345 /badges
```

When String is "a/54321/users/12345/badges" results are:

```
a/54321 /users/12345    /badges
```