# Replacing a number which comes after a tab with regex code

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am working on a question bank generator using vb.net.
Each question has 4 options which starts with a tab and  1),2)3),4)

I am using  `[^\(|\d][1-4]\)`, "#"    which replaces  1),2),3),4)(option numbers)  with #

But it also replaces 1), 2), 3),4)  when ever  it comes in the Question and Options with #.

Example

```
17.  Specific heat of certain element is 0.064, its approximate atomic mass is
    1) 100 U    2) 10 U 3) 20 U 4)  Both  2) and 3)
```

Output is

```
17. Specific heat of certain element is 0.064, its approximate atomic mass is
    # 100 U # 10 U  # 20 U  #  Both # and #
```

Expected

```
 17. Specific heat of certain element is 0.064, its approximate atomic mass is
    # 100 U # 10 U  # 20 U  #  Both 2) and 3)
```

Comment: Maybe you should separate the model from the view. You could store the questionnaire as XML instead of plain text. E.g. an option would be represented in a structured way as `<option number="1" value="100" unit="U" />` and it would be displayed as `1) 100 U`. This makes it a lot easier to read the attributes by using the classes form the [System.Xml.Linq Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq?view=net-5.0).

Comment: Also see my answer to [Questionnaire database design - which way is better?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/11970/6257).

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a positive lookbehind to assert a tab directly to the left, then match a digit 1-4 followed by a `)`

In the replacement use a `#`

```
(?<=\t)[1-4]\)
```

- `(?<=\t)` Positive lookbehind, match a tab directly to the left
- `[1-4]` Match a digit 1 to 4
- `\)` Match a `)` char

[.NET Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5ct%29%5b1-4%5d%5c%29&i=17.%09+Specific+heat+of+certain+element+is+0.064%2c+its+approximate+atomic+mass+is%0d%0a%091%29+100+U%092%29+10+U%093%29+20+U%094%29++Both++2%29+and+3%29&r=%23) | [Vb.net demo](https://ideone.com/xoqfBy)

```
Dim input As String = "17.   Specific heat of certain element is 0.064, its approximate atomic mass is" & vbCrLf &
"1) 100 U   2) 10 U 3) 20 U 4)  Both  2) and 3)"
Dim regex As Regex = New Regex("(?<=\t)[1-4]\)")
Dim result As String = regex.Replace(input, "#")
```

Output

```
17.  Specific heat of certain element is 0.064, its approximate atomic mass is
1) 100 U    # 10 U  # 20 U  #  Both  2) and 3)
```

Console.WriteLine(result)
Console.WriteLine(result)

[image]

---

Another option is to match a tab, 1+ digits and the `)`. In the replacement user a tab and `#`

```
\t\d+\)
```

[Vb.net demo](https://ideone.com/pWrb30)

Comment: Thank you , but "\t " is not working in vb.net code

Comment: @RajaGopal See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1410462/vb-net-identifier-for-tab or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30755944/regex-vb-net-regex-replace

Comment: @RajaGopal I have added a code demo for both patterns

Comment: Here `\t` is interpreted as tabulator in the regular expression. It must not be interpreted as tabulator in VB (were indeed it isn't as it would in C# if not inside a verbatim string).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes In the second code example I have used `ControlChars.Tab` to be used in the replacement.