# Reading a string line per line in C#

Tags: c#, string

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Easiest way to split a string on newlines in .net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547476/easiest-way-to-split-a-string-on-newlines-in-net)

I'm trying to read out and interpret a string line per line. I took a look at the StringReader class, but I need to find out when I'm on the last line. Here's some pseudocode of what I'm trying to accomplish:

```
while (!stringReaderObject.atEndOfStream()) {
    interpret(stringReaderObject.readLine());
}
```

Does somebody know how to do this?

Thanks!

Yvan

Comment: Not really a duplicate... both questions have different solutions.

Comment: Here's the solution that worked for me:


`private static IEnumerable<string> ReadAllLines(string multiLineString)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(multiLineString)) yield break; // Nothing to do

    using (var reader = new StringReader(multiLineString))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) is object)
        {
            yield return line;
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 79, accepted):

If you are reading it in from a file, it is easier to do just do:

```
foreach(var myString in File.ReadAllLines(pathToFile))
    interpret(myString);
```

If you are getting the string from somewhere else (a web service class or the like) it is simpler to just split the string:

```
foreach(var myString in entireString.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries))
    interpret(myString);
```

Comment: what if his string has \r\n new lines and he's on Unix?

Comment: @SB then I'm sure he would have added the "mono" and "interop" tags ;-)

Comment: Worth mentioning is `File.ReadLines` (.Net 4.0) which returns a `IEnumerable<string>` so you get lines while reading the file which is better in two ways: 1. You don't have the whole line-array in memory if you don't need it. 2. `ReadAllLines` reads the whole file before you get a single line where `ReadLines` will give you the first line as soon as it is read. (more responsive). Because he is calling a method on each line which interprets it, he properly wants `ReadLines` and not `ReadAllLines`.

Comment: **Doesn't work for me**. The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(params char[])' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @ColonelPanic, sorry the example was flawed. I have updated it. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks Klaus. Also, imho StringSplitOptions.None is a better choice, because RemoveEmptyEntries could break Markdown, eg. `"Header\r\n=====\r\n\r\nParagraph".Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: @ColonelPanic, Well I guess that depends what you use it for. But if you are parsing Markdown I suppose you are right.

Comment: Thanks @KlausByskovPedersen You saved my much time. I have used your solution to read the each line of string getting from somewhere else (string got from WebClient DownloadString from online Text file).

Answer (score 5):

Like this:

```
string line;
while (null != (line = reader.ReadLine()) {
    Process(line);
}
```

Comment: No. Like this: `while(true) { string line = reader.ReadLine(); if(line == null) { break; } Process(line); }`. That single line of code is doing too much.

Comment: @Jason - not really. Also it's the canonical pattern of use in every example I've ever seen.

Comment: @Kev: It's like a bad habit passed from generation to generation.

Comment: @Jason - no it's not. It's succinct and entirely readable. You're taking single responsibility way too far.

Comment: @Kev: Since this has nothing to do with SRP, I'm not. This is mostly about readability, and to a certain extent maintainability. Succinct code is not necessarily readable code.

Comment: @Jason - there's nothing hard to read about that code. Hell, I'm an ex-VB/Clipper programmer and could understand that when I started out with .NET. That extra `if()` is just a distraction.

Comment: @Kev: I didn't say it is hard to read.

Comment: Since OP asked about reading a string and not a file, this should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 4):

Check for null when you do a readLine - see the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stringreader.readline.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Dismissile is correct:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader.endofstream.aspx

```
while (!reader.EndOfStream) 
{ 
    string line = reader.ReadLine(); 
}
```

Comment: EndOfStream is a property of `StreamReader`. This question is asking about `StringReader`, which has no such property.

Answer (score 1):

The StreamReader class has an EndOfStream property. Have you looked into using that?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure where you are reading from. If it is from the Console, you can check for the end of inputs string like "quit" to denote end of input

```
String input;
while((input = reader.readLine()) != "quit"){
   // do something
}
```