# C# StreamReader, trouble splitting at new line

Tags: c#, streamreader

I have a global string variable - "word".

```
    string word = "";
    List<Label> labels = new List<Label>();
    int amount = 0;
```

That word is then defined/assigned in the following two functions by parsing a text document (new line delimited)

```
    void MakeLabels()
    {
        word = GetRandomWord();
        char[] chars = word.ToCharArray();
        ...
    }


    string GetRandomWord()
    {

        System.IO.StreamReader myFile = new System.IO.StreamReader(...);
        string myString = myFile.ReadToEnd();
        string[] words = myString.Split('\n');
        Random ran = new Random();
        return words[ran.Next(0, words.Length - 1)];
    }
```

And, finally, an event that validates the contents of a textbox against the "word" variable.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (textBox2.Text == word)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(...);
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(...);
            textBox2.Text = "";
            textBox1.Focus();
            Reset();
        }
```

The problem I'm having is that even when textBox2 is equivalent to "word", I'm receiving the MessageBox related to the else statement.  I think it has to do with the "word" variable carrying in the '\n'; meaning that textBox2.Text = apple and word = apple\n, thus the two variables not being equivalent.  Any suggestions?

Comment: You should wrap your file reading code in a `using (....)`. Currently your `reader` is not being disposed at all.

Comment: Can you debug your code, and show us the value of `word` and `textBox2.Text`?

Comment: Using `Environment.NewLine` instead of a hardcoded character or sequence of characters for a new line is a good practice.

Comment: the problem might be u are spliting on '\n' and you should use Environment.NewLine or if you want to hard-code it \r\n.Now since you split on '\n' the '\r' remains.and probably only the last line is fine(without the '\r').If you set a breakpoint in the words array you should see that all lines but not the last will have '\r' at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Newlines in windows environments are \r\n, not \n. Splitting on \n is insufficient.
2) Contrary to suggestions, you cannot simply call someString.Split(Environment.NewLine). 
There is no overload that simply takes a string. You could call someString.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()) but will have additional concerns you need to consider.
Say we have an input, string test = "test1\r\ntest2".  If you call test.Split('\n'), the resulting array will have two elements: array[0] will be "test1\r" and array[1] will be "test2"... 
But if you call test.Split(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()) then you'll get an array with three elements: array[0] will be "test1", array[1] will be "", and array[2] will be "test2"... Edited to add: You can combat that by calling test.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None).

3) As one person suggested, calling string.Trim() would remove \r. Thus, return words[ran.Next(0, words.Length - 1)] could be changed to return words[ran.Next(0, words.Length - 1)].Trim() to eliminate the \r without making changes to your current split code.

Comment: there is an overload in fact some overloads which accept a char[] or string[] so in the split method´s first parameter -new string[] {Environment.NewLine }-.

Comment: Ha, just made an edit to mention that. I'd initially forgotten about it.

Comment: A culmination of most of the submissions helped me on this, so thank you to all...  The Split('\n') was taking care of it's part, but I was forgetting about the remaining '\r'.  I had take care of that in the end submission.

        if (textBox2.Text == word.Trim('\r'))
            {
                MessageBox.Show(...);
            }

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that your problem is the line break at the end of the string, you should take a look at the [String.Trim()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3.aspx) method.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like the following

`string[] parseStr = myTest.Split(new string[]{Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.None);`

[CRLF parsing blues in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444284/crlf-parsing-blues-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

```
 string GetRandomWord()
  {

    string[] linse=  System .IO.File .ReadAllLines (......) ;
      string mlines = "";
        foreach (string line in linse)
          {
             if (line.Trim() != "")
                if(mlines=="")
                    mlines = line;
                else 
                mlines = mlines +"\n"+ line;
          }
        string[] words = mlines. Split('\n');

 Random ran = new Random();
    return words[ran.Next(0, words.Length - 1)];
}
```