# Extract email address(s) from string using regular expression

Tags: c#, regex

I have a requirement such that I have some text as under

```
Hello 
How r u
Email: mail3456@gg.com
Another email is aaa@zz.com
And not a valid email as invalid@.com
```

It is a string and what I have to do is that , i need to find out whether any email address is present in the string. If so i need to extract that.

Please note that there can be multiple email addresses in the string.

Is it possible to do so using regular exprerssion.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best regular expression for validating email addresses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses)

Comment: No, I am looking for a program that will extract a email address from a text. the regular expreesion for email address that i am using is private bool IsValidEmail(string email)
{
            string regexPattern = @"^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$";
            return new Regex(regexPattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).IsMatch(email);
}

Comment: If you're happy with that regex, use it (though it's not correct; see the linked question). What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: Sir, suppose in a text there can be email address or may not. If so, then i need to extract that.

Comment: I got that to work .. first i am spliting by spaces and then validating them using the method and placing them inside a list<string>.

Answer (score 3):

I think this article is what you need:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/email.html

It ranges from:

```
^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$
```

To:

```
[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?
```

Answer (score 1):

Are there truly multiple lines of text? It appears, from this example, that each line has up to one e-mail address. I would split the text into an [array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547476/easiest-way-to-split-a-string-on-newlines-in-net) first, then evaluate each individual string with your regular expression of choice.

FYI, For performance reasons, you'll probably want to instantiate your regular expression before going into a loop on the array. I was recently amazed to realize the performance hit I was taking by re-instantiating a compiled regex many times. I moved into into a singleton class so that there would only over be one instance.

Answer (score 0):

Split you string by space characters `' '`, `'\n'`... etc, then for each "word" containing '@' character apply: [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/what-is-the-best-regular-expression-for-validating-email-addresses). Even though, to me, it's exact duplicate of mentioned question.