# Regular Expression to split text in PDF file

Tags: c#, regex

I have a PDF file which I converted to .txt using an online tool. Now I want to parse the data in that and split it using regular expression. I am almost done but stuck at 1 point.

Example of data is:

```
00 41 53 Bid Form – Design/Build (Single-Prime Contract)

27 05 13.23 T1 Services
```

I want to split it like : `00 41 53 Bid Form – Design/Build (Single-Prime Contract)` and other is `27 05 13.23 T1 Services`

The regular Expression I'm using is `[0-9](\d|\ |\.)*(\D)*`

It can have numbers with spaces and/or dots, then text which can be (letters, dot, comma, `(`, `)`, `-`, and digits).

I cannot match a string if it has number in it like the "T1 Services" above.

Comment: (Paperclip voice impression) "It looks like you're trying to split text into individual lines that doesn't require Regular Expressions. Would you like help with that?"

Answer (score 2):

If I understood this correctly , you are trying to split by newline character .This is in C#.

```
string[] Result = Regex.Split(inputText, "[\r\n]+");
```

Comment: I am using the same Regex.Split command but because there is something wrong with the regular expression it is not splitting properly. So I basically have a doubt with the Regular Expression which I wrote above.

Comment: Then this will surely help you..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547476/easiest-way-to-split-a-string-on-newlines-in-net

Answer (score 0):

you can also done it with out regex Like this:

```
string phrase = ".......\n,,,,.ll..\r\n....";
string[] words;

words = phrase.Split(new string []{"\n","\r"}), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

if you want regex only then use @mhasan solution.