# constant to split string by carriage return (CR) in c#

Tags: c#, string, tokenize

I am trying to split a string into two arrays.

The first array has data at the beginning of the string which is split by the `\t` (tab) character, and the remainder somes after the first newline character (`\n`).

I tried this, thinking that's what I wanted:

```
string[] pqRecords = pqRequests.ToString().Split('\n');
```

I also tried this:

```
internal static readonly string segment = Environment.NewLine + "\t";
string[] pqRecords = pqRequests.ToString().Split(segment);
```

unfortunately the `Split` method will only take a single character.

I know there are vbcr in my pqRequests string variable because when I mouse over it and look at the text visualize there is the first line with tabs, everything else is on it's own line.

This data is taken from a txt file, and in the file, when opened in Notepad++, I can see the `CR` characters.

Is there an alternative constant in c# I should use for these CR characters?

Comment: I think you may want to try `Environment.NewLine` but it's a string, so you have to use another overload of `Split`

Comment: `File.ReadAllLines(filename)`.

Comment: Use this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547476/easiest-way-to-split-a-string-on-newlines-in-net

Comment: I tried `string[] pqRecords = pqReq.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);` but only got a single string in my array instead of several lines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`string.Split` [will happily accept](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) multiple separator characters. You just have to pass them in as an array:

```
internal static readonly string segment = Environment.NewLine + "\t";
string[] pqRecords = pqRequests.ToString().Split(segment.ToArray());
```

Of course you can (and should) write the same more clearly as

```
internal static readonly char[] separators = new[] { '\n', '\t' };
string[] pqRecords = pqRequests.ToString().Split(separators);
```

Answer (score 2):

The carriage return character is represented by '\r', is that what you need?