# Regular expressions in manipulation

Tags: regex, nsregularexpression

i have a buffer with strings. between string i have these chars \r\n 
example that i see in the buffer (string1\r\nstring3\r\nstring4.....), how i can using regular expression split this buffer in to lines.

and second question : i have in the output this string Modem Info,0,0,354869050554021

i tried to use this code:
    buff1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(imei, @"\d{15}\z").Groups[1].Value;

```
        if (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.IsMatch(imei, @"\d{15}\z") == true)
        { label1.Text = buff1; }
        else
        { label1.Text = "NOT Found"; }
```

and another option @,\d{15}$"   but it's didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Might be you don't need Regex to split strings in C#? [Easiest way to split a string on newlines in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547476/easiest-way-to-split-a-string-on-newlines-in-net)

The second question: You need to use parentheses to extract groups

```
buff1 = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Match(imei, @"(\d{15})\z").Groups[1].Value;
```

Comment: thanks for an answer, but could this expression retrieve exactly 15 digits after match of "Modem Info,0,0," i wrote @"Modem Info,0,0(\d{15})\z" but it's didn't working

Comment: It's probably new line character at the end of the string or even space. You can try \Z or \D at the end of number. @"Modem Info,0,0(\d{15})\Z" or @"Modem Info,0,0(\d{15})\D"