# Regex - Include all other line sections in their own capture groups

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have  a log file with these contents:

```
Log Started
Created Date: YY/MM/DD Time: HH:MM:SS Start
Added resources at module on YY/MM/DD HH:MM
Module 2 excecute
Resource depleted at HH:MM n pieces
Open YY/MM/DD HH:MM:SS Log to refer
Target end date of new resource YY/MM/DD approved
Log Ended. Result OK
```

Legend:

- **'YY/MM/DD'** & **'HH:MM:SS'** - these are the *unimportant* timestamps
- **Everything else** - there are the *important* data

Notes:

- As you can see, the date and time can *both* be in the same line,
  located *anywhere* within the line, and the time can be HH:MM or HH:MM:SS.
- Some lines can have *no* date/time stamps at all

I currently have the regex below, but it can only capture the date and time stamps on each line:

```
(\d{2}(\d{2})?\/\d{2}\/\d{2}(\d{2})?)|(\d{2}:\d{2}(:\d{2})?)
```

*But*, I need to be able to capture *the whole line*, and place each important and unimportant sections of data in a group.

Comment: Which language are you running this regex with? e.g. PHP, JavaScript, etc.

Comment: @David Im using C#

Comment: Do you want to capture lines with no timestamps?

Comment: @David Yes I also need to be able to capture that, Ill update my question with that, thanks.

Comment: Do you need to have the unimportant timestamps, or will just the dashes do?

Comment: @David I need all the data in the line, so the data in the dashes and the date/timestamps should ideally be in their own groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how one would do this in C# (as I've never used it before), but here are the regexes I would use:

#### 1. Get the whole line

[`(.*)\n`](https://regex101.com/r/EqQlON/2/)

Basically just matches everything until it finds a new line char `\n`.

#### 2. Get the non-timestamps on every line

Duplicate the log file into a new temporary variable and remove all the timestamps and [split the resulting string by the newline chars `\n`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514387/split-strings-into-many-strings-by-newline) [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/GCgDBg/5)

#### 3. Get the unimportant timestamps

[`(\d{2}(\d{2})?\/\d{2}\/\d{2}(\d{2})?)|(\d{2}:\d{2}(:\d{2})?)`](https://regex101.com/r/ZEo0VH/1/)

Your regex was quite good and worked like a charm :)

Comment: Also, do try regex101's code generator feature, it might be helpful for your case.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very concise suggestions, but how would I change the regex if the dashes are actual string? Ive only replaced the important data with dashes for illustration purposes though, so in reality they are sentences, phrases, numbers, etc.

Comment: @slimjourney Oh, that would have been good to know, perhaps you can update your question with sample data and new requirements? Anyways, I'll see if I can find a better solution for that.

Comment: Yeah Im sorry about that, updated the above sample lines accordingly. P.S. the sample data I replaced above are just some placeholders since the log couldnt be shared, but hopefully it gives you the idea.

Comment: @slimjourney Ok, thanks for the sample data. I've updated my answer (just step 2), can you check again? P.S. you may need to update your question where you say: _'-' these are the important data_

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick help, Im now able to slowly incorporate your suggestions into my code.

Answer (score 1):

First you have to group each line using `(.*)\n`. Then you have to replace the date format using the regex from the grouped string.

Check here. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Do you have an idea how I can replace the date/time stamp with a group of dummy string depending on how long the captured group was? For example, if I capture HH:MM:SS Id replace it with 8 "X's", while if I capture "HH:MM" Id only replace it with 5 "X's"

Comment: @slimjourney This is not possible with pure regex, you'd need to do two different search and replaces, 1st replace HH:MM:SS with 8 "X's", 2nd replace HH:MM with 5 "X's".

Comment: @David I see, Ill have to ask a different question regarding C# replacing a whole string with only 1 character then, again thanks a lot for the help.

Comment: OK @slimjourney no problem :) Did my answer help you? If so can you [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)?

Comment: my $s = "HH:MM";
$s =~s/(HH\:MM(\:SS)?)/'x' x length($1)/e;
print $s."\n";