# How to parse this particular string?

Tags: c#

I want to parse this string: `"2.8\r\n2.52\r\n"` to just get 2.8 and 2.52. How can I go about doing something like this? I tried to using .Split() but I'm not sure what to pass as parameters to get what I am looking for.

Comment: Use a Regular Expression.

Comment: There are a lot of duplicates of this question [split strings into many strings by newline?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21514387/split-strings-into-many-strings-by-newline)

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski cool

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`String.Split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split?view=netcore-3.1) should work fine:

```
string[] res = "2.8\r\n2.52\r\n".Split("\r\n", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries); // array with {"2.8", "2.52"}
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to split by `Environment.NewLine` which in here would be `\r\n`

```cs
var result = "2.8\r\n2.52\r\n".Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Edit:
`Environment.NewLine` depends on your environment as you can guess so to be on the safe side you can also use the exact string (`\r\n`) as a delimiter.