# Grabbing part of a String

Tags: c#

I have a string that I am grabbing that is input as:

```
05/22/2015
Eligibility
05/06/2015
Date of Death
```

I need `05/06/2015`.  The dates will change as the program runs through a database, and I am just a little unsure on how to always be grabbing the correct one.

Comment: The requirement here is extremely unclear.

Comment: Can you include what you've tried and narrow down the exact output you're expecting? Also, have you researched this? I used your exact original title in google and found tons of plausible solutions :)

Comment: So it's always the third line?  Just call 'Split' as detailed here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547476/easiest-way-to-split-a-string-on-newlines-in-net
 
And then grab the appropriate element from the array.

Comment: I am sorry for the unclear question.  I am very new to the site in general and realize I was too vague with it.  It is always the third line.  Thank you for the recommendation.

Comment: Welcome to the site! As a tip for next time, I'd suggest you browse through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help) as it has some really great tips on how to get started and what kind of questions are on-topic here.

Comment: @CarrieKendall Understood.  Thank you for being so welcoming!  I will make sure I look at the help center before posting again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So you need the second date only?   Is it always going to be the 3rd line?  If so you can do

```
var secondDate = myData.Split(new [] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)[2];
```

If the new line isn't for certain; /n vs /r/n, use:

```
var secondDate = myDate.Split(Environment.Newline.ToCharArray(), StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[2];
```

Comment: This depends on the environment, but will most likely return `Eligibility`.

Comment: @Rawling An array uses index, indexes start at 0.  If I use `[1]` then the outcome would have been `Eligibility`.

Comment: [`String.Split(char[])`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a.aspx) splits on any of the characters in the input array. Assuming the input has standard C# linebreaks, the resulting array will be `{ "05/22/2015", "", "Eligibility", "", "05/06/2015", "", "Date of Death" }`, the `[2]`th element of which is `"Eligibility"`.

Comment: @Rawling thanks for the breakdown.  I've adjusted my answer to use a string array.

Answer (score -1):

If I understand you correctly, your string has 4 lines and you want the part of the string between linebreak 2 and 3.

Search for the positions of the second and third linebreak `\n` and use the substring derived of these positions.

Comment: yes that is correct.  I am only interested in grabbing the second date (05/06/2015) without either title or the first date.