# How do I split a string on an empty line using .Split()?

Tags: c#, split

For a class project I have to load a text file into a linked list. So far, I have been able to read from the file, but I am struggling to split it up into sections so that I can put it into the linked list.

For example, I would like to split these items up at the empty lines:

David
Hunter
No1
Admin

John
Smith
No11
Sales

Jane 
Appleby
No5
Accounts

I have tried `String[] people = record.Split('\n');` but of course, this just splits it at every line.

I have also tried:
 `String[] people = record.Split('\n\r');` 
 `String[] people = record.Split('\r\n');`
 `String[] people = record.Split('\n\n');`
but it won't compile due to "too many characters in character literal"

Could anyone please suggest a way to do this (preferably without regex)?

Comment: Please show us how you “read get the file”.

Comment: Split on `"\r\n\r\n"` - notice double quotes for string rather than single quotes for character.

Comment: Post the actual input of text file and also attach the code that extracts `record` variable.

Comment: `txt.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)`

Comment: This is not a duplicate of [split a string on newlines](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547476/easiest-way-to-split-a-string-on-newlines-in-net), because OP wants only to split on *empty* lines.

Comment: @SkyFang why Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine?  Would have thought record.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) would suffice

Comment: @mick `Environment.NewLine` just one line,in windows it seems to be `\r\n`,so need to use `Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine`

Comment: @SkyFang Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray() ==  { '\r', '\n' } && Environment.NewLine == "\r\n"  so Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine wouldn't be correct

Comment: if anything other than Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }) you would want Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine, "\r", "\n" })

Comment: @Mick that would break on any "\r\n", "\r" or "\n". The OP wants to break on an empty line, i.e. two consecutive newlines ("\r\n\r\n").

Comment: @SkyFang's solution was the only one I could get to compile, but I really appreciate everyone's help and suggestions. Thanks guys!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can get it accomplished by using

```
string[] people = record.Split(new string[] { "\r\n\r\n" },
                               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

or

```
string[] people = record.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine },
                               StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

What it does is it removes empty entries with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` and then splits where two linebreaks are right after each other.

Comment: This worked, thank you!

Also a big thank you to everyone else who offered help!