# Splitting a long string in c#

Tags: c#, string

I have this string and I need it split multiple ways.

```
Pending order
Sell EUR/USD
Price 1.0899
Take profit  at 1.0872
Stop loss at 1.0922
From 23:39 18-01-2016 GMT Till 03:39 19-01-2016 GMT
```

That is the full string i need to split it as such

```
string SellorBuy = "Sell";
string Price = "1.0889";
string Profit = "1.0872";
string StopLoss = "1.0922";
```

The Numbers are different every-time but i still need them to be split into there own strings. I have no idea how to go about this. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

What I've tried

```
string message = messager.TextBody;
message.Replace(Environment.NewLine, "|");
string[] Spliter;
char delimiter = '|';
Spliter = message.Split(delimiter);
```

It didn't seem to add the "|" to it.

Comment: Consider using `System.Text.RegularExpressions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the string on newlines then process each line based on the first word of that line.  More info on splitting on newlines here... https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547483/4322803

```
// Split the string on newlines
string[] lines = theText.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None);

// Process each line
foreach(var line in lines){
  var words = line.Split(' ');
  var firstWord = parts[0];

  switch (firstWord){
    case "Price":
      Price = words[1];
      break;
    case "Take":
      Profit = words[words.Length - 1];
      break;
    // etc
  }
}
```

The code above is really just to get you started.  You should probably create a class called `PendingOrder` with strongly typed properties for `Price`, `Profit` etc (e.g. use `float` or `decimal` for the numbers rather than strings) and pass the raw text in via the constructor to populate the properties.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for.