# print first word of last line in a string C#

Tags: c#, string

> 1 AYAN PAL    40  Male        CNF S7  49 (LB) CNF S7  49 (LB)
>
> 2 D PRADHAN   26  Male        CNF S7  52 (LB) CNF S7  52 (LB)
>
> 3 CHRISTINA JOY   34  Female  CNF S4  5 (MB)  CNF S4  5 (MB)
>
> 4 J CHARLES DANNIE    34  Male    CNF S4  6 (UB)  CNF S4  6 (UB)
>
> 5 ANUDEEP 27  Male        CNF S9  9 (LB)  CNF S9  9 (LB)
>
> 6 SAI KUMAR   25  Male        CNF S9  12 (LB) CNF S9  12 (LB)

I have this `data` in a `string` and i want to print the first word of a last line  on a `LABEL` and the data is `dynamic`

Comment: Does string contain any delimiters?

Comment: Split the text by the delimiter line (normally "\n"), then the last item of the splitted array will be the last line. Just split again by " ".

Comment: NO string does not contains any delimiters

Comment: @AngelPriyanka the delimiter is not visible, it is hidden you can't see it. (Unless using a debugger or some special text editor eg Notepad++)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combination of `Split` and `FirstOrDefault` must do the trick:

```
var lastWordOfLastLine = multiLineData.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                                        .LastOrDefault().Split(' ').FirstOrDefault();
```

To Break it down:

```
string lastLine = multiLineData.Split(
           new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                              .LastOrDefault();

string lastWord = lastLine == null ? null : lastLine.Split(' ').FirstOrDefault();
```

I prefer the second method as it handles null values a doesn't throw a  `NullReferenceExpception`

Comment: Cool happy to help you

Comment: Nice and clear solution. Just to add - if he has to handle different types of line breaks then use `new string[] { "\r\n", "\n" }` as stated [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547476/easiest-way-to-split-a-string-on-newlines-in-net)

Comment: `Environment.NewLine` retrieves the appropriate new line for the current Operating system AFAIK.