# Get the part of a string before new line symbol

Tags: c#, string, split

I do want to get all the text before the first `\r\n\` symbol. For example,

`lalal lalal laldlasdaa daslda\r\n\Prefersaasda reanreainrea`

I would need: `lalal lalal laldlasdaa daslda`. The above string can be empty, but it also may not contain any `'\r\n\'` symbol." How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Easiest way to split a string on newlines in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547476/easiest-way-to-split-a-string-on-newlines-in-net)

Comment: Please note your input is not a valid string, their is an additional `\` after `\r\n` that make this input invalid

Comment: That is not a good duplicate since it has too much overhead compared to the answers given @VinKel

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `IndexOf` to get the position, then use `Substring` to get the first part:

```
string s = "lalal lalal laldlasdaa daslda\r\n Prefersaasda reanreainrea";

int positionOfNewLine = s.IndexOf("\r\n");

if (positionOfNewLine >= 0)
{
    string partBefore = s.Substring(0, positionOfNewLine);
}
```

Comment: @Toshi:  `s` was not a valid string, because of `\` after `\r\n`, now it will compile

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Split` like this

```
string mystring = @"lalal lalal laldlasdaa daslda\r\n\Prefersaasda reanreainrea";
string mylines = mystring.Split(new string[] { @"\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
```

[image: Screen Shot]

Whereas if the string is like

```
string mystring = "lalal lalal laldlasdaa daslda\r\n Prefersaasda reanreainrea";
string mylines = mystring.Split(new string[] { Environment.NewLine }, StringSplitOptions.None)[0];
```

`Environment.NewLine` will also work with it. The with `\r\n\P` is making that string an invalid string thus `\r\n P` makes it a new line

Comment: Splitting is very expensive on long strings if you just want the first part.

Comment: You are working with a broken string and thus your `@"\r\n"` is very wrong. It will take `\\` literally! **This will not work for the problem OP is facing.**

Answer (score 3):

Hope that this is what you are looking for:

```
string inputStr = "lalal lalal laldlasdaa daslda\r\nPrefersaasda reanreainrea";
int newLineIndex =  inputStr.IndexOf("\r\n");
if(newLineIndex != -1)
{ 
  string outPutStr = inputStr.Substring(0, newLineIndex );
  // Continue
}
else
{
    // Display message no new line character 
}
```

Checkout an example [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/mVIbfI)