# How can I use a resource text file with File.ReadAllLines?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d-games

I've got a file with some names of files in it for loading prefabs. I was loading the files with File.ReadAllLines(hardPathToFile) but that doesn't work when you build. You need to use a "Resource" folder. So I tried using `Resource.Load(fileName)` however that doesn't bring out a list or array. I then tried `File.ReadAllLines(Resource.Load(fileName, typeOf(TextAsset)) as TextAsset))` but that doesn't work because the resource that gets loaded isn't a string filepath.

Here's the full code:

```
void getList(string filePath)
{
    prefabObjects.Clear();
    //Read all the lines from the file. File loaded from resources

    print((Resources.Load(filePath, typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset).text);

    var prefabs = File.ReadAllLines((Resources.Load(filePath, typeof(TextAsset)) as TextAsset).text);
    print(prefabs);
    foreach (var prefab in prefabs)
    {
        print(prefab);
        GameObject newPrefab = Resources.Load(prefab, typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject;
        prefabObjects.Add(newPrefab);
    }
}
```

How can I get this to work?

All help appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: @Fredrik, Yeah it's only the filename now. That's just left from when I used the hard path.

Comment: I see, then the problem lies elsewhere!

Comment: @Slai, I don't believe so. That's about C# resources not Unity ones. It doesn't answer my question at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you previously used a hard path to the file, I'm guessing you did something like `/path/to/file.txt`. With [Resources.Load()](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html) you don't specify the file endings (`file.txt` -> `file`).

Here's what I did in my project to read the contents of a textfile:

```
var api = Resources.Load("ConnectionString") as TextAsset;
var apiKey = api.text;
```

Comment: would the `apiKey` variable be able to be split into a list with something like `File.ReadAllLines()` or is it just a string?

Comment: It would be the entire contents: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/TextAsset-text.html

It would be possible to use .Split() on this, for instance on newlines: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547476/easiest-way-to-split-a-string-on-newlines-in-net

Comment: I've managed to get it working with `.Split()` Thanks :)