# C# merge lines of strings into groups of 3 at a time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a string like this (including newlines)

```
A2,
10.22,
-57,
A,
10.23,
-68,
A2,
10.24,
-60,
LB,
10.25,
-62,
```

I am trying to make this string to look like this:

```
 A2,10.22,-57,
 A,10.23,-68,
 A2,10.24,-60,
 LB,10.25,-62,
```

I need to join string in every 3 line i have tried :

```
int numLines = a.Split('\n').Length;
for (int i = 0; i < numLines; i += 3)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = a.Replace("\n", "");
}
```

But it is not working for me. Please help me out

Comment: I don't think that code is doing what you think it is.  It reads that you just keep sending a replace "\n" with "" to the same control, as many times as that loop runs.  Try send the individual pieces of text you want to a new string, and then replacing richTextBox1.Text once, at the end.

Comment: Please, describe what exactly is not working. What did you get as a result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that the input is actually coming from a file here.

```
var file = //file path
var sb = new StringBuilder();
var lineNum = 1;
var output = string.Empty;

using (var reader = new StreamReader(file))
{
    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
    {
        var line = reader.ReadLine();
        if (lineNum % 3 == 0)
        {
            output += sb.ToString() + "\n";
            sb.Clear();
        }
        else
            sb.Append(line);

        lineNum++;
    }
}

richTextBox1.Text = output;
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also approach this with LINQ, by using the [index overload of `.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to retain a running count of the line numbers, and then to group them into groups of 3 - I've used integer division to `Floor` the line index, 3 at a time, but there are likely other suitable ways.

```
var groups = values.Select((s, idx) => (Index: idx / 3, Value: s))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index);
```

Where each item in the groups above will be `IEnumerable<(Index, Value)>`.

You'll also need to be wary of [newlines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1547483/314291) - these may be `\r\n` in Windows, not just the `\n` you've indicated.

Here's an example:

```
var a =
@"A2,
10.22,
-57,
A,
10.23,
-68,
A2,
10.24,
-60,
LB,
10.25,
-62,";

var values = a.Split(new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
var groups = values.Select((s, idx) => (Index: idx / 3, Value: s))
    .GroupBy(x => x.Index);

foreach (var grp in groups)
{
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", grp.Select(x => x.Value)));
}
```

Since you've already got commas at the end of each string (including the last one), there's no need to add another separator.

*Output:*

```
A2,10.22,-57,
A,10.23,-68,
A2,10.24,-60,
LB,10.25,-62,
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not use the array that the split gives you instead?

```
var newArr = a.Split('\n');

for (int i = 0; i < newArr.Length; i += 3)
{
    richTextBox1.Text = newArr[i] + newArr[i + 1] + newArr[i + 2];
}
```

Just don't forget to check the length of the arrays so that you don't get a IndexOutOfRange Exception.

Answer (score 1):

Try this solution which is a combination of `linq` and `for` loop

```
var result = "";
var items = yourInputString.Split('\n');
for(var i=0; i<items.Count();i=i+3)
{
    result += string.Join(",",items.Skip(i).Take(3))+"\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `Aggregate` function

```
var outPutList = data.Replace("\r", string.Empty).Replace("\n", string.Empty).Split(",").Aggregate(new StringBuilder(""), (x, y) =>
{
    if (double.TryParse(y, out double parsedValue))
        x.Append(" " + parsedValue);
    else
    {
       x.Append(Environment.NewLine);
       x.Append(y.Trim());
    }
    return x;
});
  richTextBox1.Text = outPutList.ToString();
```

Here is the output

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {            
        var Lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("input.txt");
        var Result = new StringBuilder();
        var SB = new StringBuilder();

        for (var i = 0; i < Lines.Length; i++)
        {
            SB.Append(Lines[i]);

            if ((i+1) % 3 == 0)
            {
                Result.Append($"{SB.ToString()}{Environment.NewLine}");
                SB.Clear();
            }
        }

        System.IO.File.WriteAllText("output.txt", Result.ToString());

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this works

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //put your string in a textxbox with multiline property set to true
    string[] s = textBox1.Text.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "").Split(',');
    string r = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; i++)
    {
        r = r + s[i] + ",";
        if ((i + 1) % 3 == 0)
            r = r + "+";
    }
    if (r.Substring(r.Length - 1, 1) == ",")
        r = r.Substring(0, r.Length - 1);
    if (r.Substring(r.Length - 1, 1) == "+")
        r = r.Substring(0, r.Length - 1);
    string[] finalArrayString = r.Trim().Split('+');

    //just for show the result
    textBox1.Text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < finalArrayString.Length; i++)
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + finalArrayString[i] + "\r\n";
}
```

hope it helps you