# String[] to int[]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I use Visual Studio 8.7.9, Unity 2019.3.13f1

When I try to convert string[] to int[],

```
string score = reader.ReadToEnd();
string[] scores = score.Split('\n');
int[] scoreSorter = new int[scores.Length + 1];
for(int i =0; i <scores.Length; i++)
{
    scoreSorter[i] = Convert.ToInt32(scores[i]);
    
    foreach(var s in scoreSorter)
    {
        Array.Sort(scoreSorter);
        Debug.Log(s);
        highScore.text = "Рекорды: \n" + scoreSorter[0] + "\n" + scoreSorter[1] + "\n" + scoreSorter[2] + "\n" + scoreSorter[3];
    }
    
}
```

I get this error in my unity console:

> FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.
> System.Number.StringToNumber (System.String str,
> System.Globalization.NumberStyles options, System.Number+NumberBuffer&
> number, System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info, System.Boolean
> parseDecimal) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
> System.Number.ParseInt32 (System.String s,
> System.Globalization.NumberStyles style,
> System.Globalization.NumberFormatInfo info) (at
> <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0) System.Int32.Parse
> (System.String s, System.IFormatProvider provider) (at
> <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0) System.Convert.ToInt32
> (System.String value) (at <437ba245d8404784b9fbab9b439ac908>:0)
> ButtonAction.ButtonClickHighScore () (at
> Assets/Scripts/UI/ButtonAction.cs:73)

My aim is to get each number in array, sort them and display on the scoreboard.
Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The error happens when some input value cannot be converted to an integer in the call to Convert.ToInt32. I suggest to add a _Debug.Log(scores[i])_ just before the convert line. So you will know which text is causing problems.

Comment: Please log elements from scores array or use debugger to understand which values it contains.

Comment: Perhaps try TryParse instead, use the debugger to step through the problem, and finally: Try using .Trim() to ensure there are no leading or trailing `" "`.

Comment: Instead of `\n` try `Environment.NewLine` or try to split on all newline formats `string[] lines = theText.Split(
    new[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n" },
    StringSplitOptions.None
);` - see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547476/easiest-way-to-split-a-string-on-newlines-in-net

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have a newline character at the end of the input.

Change this line:

```
string[] scores = score.Split('\n');
```

To this:

```
string[] scores = score.Split(new char[] {'\n'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Or just File.ReadAllLines

Answer (score 0):

One of the strings was not a valid integer. Find out what string it is and fix it.

Comment: I use .txt file to save data. Here is the example of when it gives me error. When I fill it with different numbers, the same mistake. https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q6xmcMlJNBpO2ukZTkJyjoINzyMqITp5/view?usp=sharing