# "\n\r" String to Array C#

Tags: c#, file.readalllines

When I do a Reader.ReadToEnd() it returns \n\r ,
How do I convert that String into array without '\n\r' ,
Even better, how do I give a signal that \n\r is a new index in the array?

Comment: Use ``Split`` function based on ``\n\r``

Comment: Windows line endings are usually `\r\n`, not `\n\r`

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547476/easiest-way-to-split-a-string-on-newlines-in-net?

Comment: Just use `ReadLines()` method

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
var array = Reader.ReadToEnd().Split("\r\n", StringSplitOptions.None);
```

This will remove all the new-line characters from the array and leave what is in between them as seperate elements.

The `StringSplitOptions` has enum values that determine whether empty (`StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`) or white-space (`StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries`) substrings should be omitted.

Answer (score 0):

If your input lines are coming from the OS you run at, you can:

```
string[] lines = Reader.ReadToEnd().Split(Environment.NewLine, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

This way you don't care about the environment of you code.