# How to use \n new line in VB msgbox() ...?

Tags: vb6, newline, msgbox

What is the alternative to `\n` (for new line) in a `MsgBox()`?

Comment: Are you asking about VB.NET or VB 6?

Comment: See also *[End-of-line identifier in VB.NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1399268)*.

Comment: @PeterMortensen who decided this question should be changed to VB.Net?

Answer (score 114, accepted):

- **for VB:** `vbCrLf` or `vbNewLine`
- **for VB.NET:** `Environment.NewLine` or `vbCrLf` or `Constants.vbCrLf`

Info on VB.NET new line: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx

The info for `Environment.NewLine` came from [Cody Gray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/366904/cody-gray) and [J Vermeire](https://stackoverflow.com/users/280201/j-vermeire)

Comment: Do not use `vbCrLf` for VB.NET code! That's only there for compatibility with ported VB 6 applications. You should be using `Environment.NewLine` instead, as suggested in J. Vermeire's answer.

Comment: I agree with you that Environment.NewLine should be used, but because it is cross platform. It returns \r\n for Window, but only \n for unix/linux based platforms.

Comment: Yes, that's a very good reason to use it. Considering that alternative implementations of the CLR (like Mono) support VB.NET, it's a good idea to write code with an eye towards platform independence. Beyond that, adopting standard .NET Framework idioms, rather than holdovers for backwards compatibility purposes, is always a good idea. The biggest mistake any VB.NET programmer will make is assuming it's the same language as VB 6. **It's emphatically not!** The true object-orientation is only scratching the surface of the differences. Pretending otherwise is doing yourself an injustice.

Comment: Down vote because it doesn't work for me. Calling EditPoint.Insert(vbNewLine) in a VB macro inserts \r\n. vbLf is the correct answer to the asked question.

Comment: I just declared a public string called `n`... just for convenience. (`Public n As String = Environment.NewLine`)

Answer (score 34):

Try using `vbcrlf` for a newline

```
msgbox "This is how" & vbcrlf & "to get a new line"
```

Comment: The example is appreciated because I don't work with VB and didn't know the concatenation format.  They are evidently not interpreted within double quotes.

Answer (score 24):

These are the character sequences to create a new line:

- `vbCr` is the carriage return (return to line beginning),
- `vbLf` is the line feed (go to next line)
- `vbCrLf` is the carriage return / line feed (similar to pressing Enter)

**I prefer `vbNewLine` as it is system independent** (`vbCrLf` may not be a true new line on some systems)

Comment: @Andrew - during my college days when i do programming in vb

Comment: Theoretically, I suppose you're right. But in every implementation that I've seen, `vbNewLine` is simply defined as `vbCrLf`. There isn't any difference.

Comment: I wouldn't change anything. I agree with you the way it is. I think `vbNewLine` more clearly expresses your intent. It's obviously been *designed* to insert a new line. I was just providing auxiliary commentary. "Under the hood", they do the same thing. Implementation details like that shouldn't leak into your code.

Answer (score 17):

Use the [`Environment.NewLine` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline.aspx)

Comment: This is the correct solution for VB.NET. Skip the `vbCrLf`/`vbNewLine` nonsense unless you're using VB 6.

Answer (score 11):

Add a `vbNewLine` as:

```
"text1" & vbNewLine & "text2"
```

Answer (score 5):

An alternative to Environment.NewLine is to use :

```
Regex.Unescape("\n\tHello World\n")
```

from System.Text.RegularExpressions

This allows you to escape Text without Concatenating strings as you can in C#, C, java

Answer (score 4):

The correct format is :

```
"text1" + vbNewLine + "text2"
```

Answer (score 2):

Use the command "vbNewLine"

Example

```
Hello & vbNewLine & "World"
```

will show up as
Hello on one line and World on another

Answer (score 2):

You can use **Environment.NewLine** OR **vbCrLF** OR **vbNewLine**

```
MsgBox($"Hi!{Environment.NewLine}I'M HERE")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use  carriage return character (Chr(13)), a linefeed character (Chr(10)) also like

```
MsgBox "Message Name: " & objSymbol1.Name & Chr(13) & "Value of BIT-1: " & (myMessage1.Data(1)) & Chr(13) & "MessageCount: " & ReceiveMessages.Count
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Module MyHelpers
    <Extension()>
    Public Function UnEscape(ByVal aString As String) As String

       Return Regex.Unescape(aString)

    End Function
End Module
```

Usage:

```
console.writeline("Ciao!\n".unEscape)
```

Answer (score 1):

On my side I created a sub MyMsgBox replacing \n in the prompt by ControlChars.NewLine

Answer (score 1):

A lot of the stuff above didn't work for me.
What did end up working is

```
Chr(13)
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be Chr(10)?

Comment: @LenardBartha likely not https://stackoverflow.com/a/38792168/2727437

Comment: Which is equivalent to the `vbCr` [built in constant](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/miscellaneous-constants).

Answer (score 1):

do not forget to set the Multiline property to true in textbox

Answer (score 0):

msgbox("your text here" & Environment.NewLine & "more text") is the easist way. no point in making your code harder or more ocmplicated than you need it to be...

Comment: Your answer (`Environment.NewLine`) was already given 3 years ago and is the highest voted answer. This is more like commentary. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have [sufficient reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment) you will be able to comment on any post.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:
`MessageBox.Show("YourString" & vbcrlf & "YourNewLineString")`

Answer (score -1):

The message box must end with a text and not with a variable