# Difference between chr(13) and chr(10)

Tags: crystal-reports

What is the difference between `chr(13)` and `chr(10)` in Crystal Reports?

I know `chr(13)` is used as a line break. But one of our reports uses this line:

```
{Address1} + chr(13) + chr(10) + {Address2}
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`Chr(10)` is the Line Feed character and `Chr(13)` is the Carriage Return character.

You *probably* won't notice a difference if you use only one or the other, but you might find yourself in a situation where the output doesn't show properly with only one or the other. So it's safer to include both.

---

Historically, Line Feed would move down a line but not return to column 1:

```
This  
    is  
        a  
            test.
```

Similarly Carriage Return would return to column 1 but *not* move down a line:

```
This  
is  
a  
test.
```

Paste this into a text editor and then choose to "show all characters", and you'll see both characters present at the end of each line. Better safe than sorry.

Comment: is there a page that show a reference of all the key codes in vba ?

Comment: The "key codes" is just ascii values. Link: http://www.asciitable.com/