# Can somebody help out what is the issue with the following GAS code

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, line-breaks

I'm trying to split multylines in a cell using '\n' with the following code, however, the logger returns [] empty list can somebody help me out finding the issue
Thanks in advance

```
for (var i = 0; i < lrIndexArtf; i++) {
  if (rngArtf[i] != "") {
    var cellValue = rngArtf[i].toString();
    var linesArray = cellValue.split('\n');

    for (var k = 0; k < linesArray.length; k++) {
      data_list.push(linesArray[k]);
    }

  }

} //end of loop
Logger.log(data_list)
```

Comment: Show `cellValue`. It probably doesn't contain `\n`

Comment: Please define lrIndexArtf

Comment: Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Use [fromCharCode](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromcharcode.asp)

`String.fromCharCode(10);`

There is a chance it is char(13). See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764176/difference-between-chr13-and-chr10) for more detail.