# Defining bytes in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I am in the process of learning i386 assembly. As I was reading through some of the sample code in one of the tutorials on defining bytes and words, I noticed two hex values following the string that was assigned.

```
msg1 db "Enter a digit ", 0xA,0xD 
   len1 equ $- msg1
```

There seems to be no reference made to what these values mean.  Will somebody shine some light on this?

Comment: Normally `0A` and `0D` in ASCII represent `LF` (Line Feed) and `CR` (Carriage Return) commands.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38764176/difference-between-chr13-and-chr10

Comment: The two chars `0xA,0xD` are a Windows NewLine. On Linux, a NewLine is `0x0A`, but on Windows this it it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character

Comment: On a practical note, if a command line program outputs a string and doesn't terminate it with a newline, once the program finishes, the command prompt will appear at the end of the string, not on the next line as anyone would expect. So the CR/LF pair is there in the string for that purpose.

Comment: It is odd that a prompt would include the characters to start a new line.  ~Normally we would want the user to enter digits on the same line as in *Enter a digit: **4***.  Where the user types the **4**.