# Displaying string on 2 lines in Visual Basic

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am trying to get some code in Visual Basic to display on two lines. Here is my code below,

```
Dim v_names As String()

Dim v_nums As String()

Dim v_list As String
v_names = Me.PN_ComboBox.SelectedValue.Split(":")(3).Split(";")
v_nums = Me.PN_ComboBox.SelectedValue.Split(":")(4).Split(";")
v_list = ""

For i = 0 To (v_names.Length - 1)

     v_list = v_list & v_nums(i) & ":" & v_names(i)

Next i

Me.Vnumber_Label.Text = v_list
```

Currently it is displaying as:

```
123: bill:456: bob
```

I would like it to display as:

```
123: bill
456: bob
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: This help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152042/how-to-use-n-new-line-in-vb-msgbox

Answer (score 0):

The constant "VbCrLf" can help you with that, I just searched on google :|
And StackOverflow itself has topics about it answered

```
v_list = v_list & v_nums(i) & ":" & v_names(i) & VbCrLf
```

or

```
v_list = v_list & v_nums(i) & ":" & v_names(i) & Environment.NewLine
```

Comment: try: Environment.NewLine

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim fields = Me.PN_ComboBox.SelectedValue.Split(":")
Dim v_names As String() = fields(3).Split(";")
Dim v_nums As String() = fields(4).Split(";")
Dim strings = v_names.Zip(v_nums, Function(name, num) $"{name}:{num}")

Me.Vnumber_Label.Text = String.Join("<br/>", strings)
```

Here's a working test:

https://dotnetfiddle.net/7x7MQX

---

Oops! I missed the `asp.net` tag. In an ASP.Net context, a simple line break is not enough. Html doesn't care, and treats all white space the same. You need `<br/>`. I've updated the answer above to account for this.

Furthermore, putting `<br/>` into the label text might not be enough, because the label control can html-encode it. You need to set the label to not do that (and I'm drawing a blank where to do this at moment, but now that you know it needs to be done you can look up where as quickly as I).

Comment: I tried this but I'm getting quite a few errors.
"$" is not a valid character
"Function" is not a valid identifier
num and name are not declared.

I'm using VB language if that helps. I'm VERY new at this.

Comment: What version of VB.Net/Visual Studio? The `$` is for string interpolation, which is a fairly recent feature.

Comment: I've got the 2019 version

Comment: Seems like it should work then. Maybe check your Imports directives https://dotnetfiddle.net/7x7MQX

Comment: @ChristopherWatson I've updated some things in the answer.

Comment: @ChristopherWatson Please accept the answer by clicking the check mark (tick mark) to the left of the answer. This will help future readers and earn you a few reps.