# Is it possible to display multiple text boxes at 1 time (upon running) in VBS

Tags: vbscript, popup, messagebox

If I do:

```
MsgBox "my text or whatever"
MsgBox "my text or whatever"
```

They just go 1 after the other and if I do:

```
MsgBox "my text or whatever" + MsgBox "my text or whatever"
```

I get an error. I am very new to VBS but I couldn't really find much on this. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: It would help to provide some detail about why you want two message boxes on screen at once. Maybe an alternative approach can be used, such as an HTA, which will allow you to use HTML/CSS to display whatever you like. Please edit your question to add detail.

Comment: If you mean that you want display two or more messages in one MsgBox you can do it by adding `vbCrlf` otherwise , you can't !

Comment: @Hackoo It can be done indirectly by spawning a separate script for each `MsgBox`, but is that really the best solution? Probably not (unless it's a stupid prank app).

Comment: Conceptually a `MessageBox()` (called `MsgBox` in Basic) is a modal dialog. There are two types of dialog - modal and modeless. For modal dialog the program calls the `MessageBox()`, and all program code stops (in single threaded VBS) until that procedure returns with a result. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlgbox/about-dialog-boxes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use \n new line in VB msgbox() ...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5152042/how-to-use-n-new-line-in-vb-msgbox)